# Palantir Foundry fail to set link between two objects

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

When I try to link two object in my code repositories into a TS function as explain in the foundry documentation:
`// Set an Employee's supervisor employee.supervisor.set(newSupervisor);`

There is my code:

```
@Edits(A,B)
    @OntologyEditFunction()
    private Link_to_B(a:A,b:B):void{b.A.clear(),
    a.B.set(b);}
```

I get the following issue :

```
Error Parameters: {}
TypeError: r.map is not a function
    at Function.convertToPhonographTypeV2 (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:84:22866)
    at t.TypeConvertingPropertyStore.convertToPhonographType (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:371:6237)
    at t.TypeConvertingPropertyStore.set (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:371:5997)
    at t.DefaultObjectStorageProvider.setPropertyValue (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:100:35623)
    at t.DefaultObjectStorageProvider.addSingleKeyLink (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:100:38897)
    at t.DefaultObjectStorageProvider.setSingleKeyLink (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:100:38627)
    at Object.set (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:100:37746)
    at Object.set (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:331:10356)
    at Object.set (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:334:1414)
    at Object.set (FunctionsFunctionsIsolateRuntimePackagePackage:334:4108)
```

I try to link those to object, the linkType already exist, but I cannot asign those two objects.

Comment: Depending of the object A, i can also get this error :
```Expected at most one linked object. Check if the cardinality of the object in the link should be set to 'MANY' instead or if there are erroneous links in the data
```

Comment: (1) What is the cardinality of this link type? (2) Are you able to create a no-code Action using the Ontology Manager app that lets you link these objects? I would suggest trying #2 in order to determine whether the issue lies with your Function or with the Action. Finally, (3) do you get this error for ALL objects you try linking or only some? To test #3, find two objects that you verify do not have any links and try linking those two object.s

Comment: I check my data manually, those two object set are already linked to one or multiple values. In some case I had à succes with my clean() method. It appelés that the ontology is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my Writeback dataset and I find the problem.
These link A to B is defined as a One to One link in the Ontology.
But in the writeback, multiple A or link to a B and multible B are link to a A.
So it completely broke the code and make it unusable. To fix the bug we need to change the Ontology.